# How to code Websockets/AJAX for frequent database updates? Or is there a better method?

Tags: javascript, html, sql, ajax, websocket

I’m making a html & Javascript game and I’m currently trying to write some code that will show the player’s gold balance on the screen and make it decrement by 1 every time the player clicks on a Javascript object (this object is placed in a div on the html page).

I’m going to grab the balance from my database using AJAX on page load, and then place it inside a `<div>` but I have no idea how to make this figure decrement by 1 every time the Javascript object is clicked.

I don’t want the figure to decrement below 0. Instead, whenever it reaches 0 I want to initiate a Javascript modal to inform the player that they’ve run out of coins.

~~

Originally I was trying to use websockets to display the player’s balance on screen, but I found it very confusing (I’m a beginner at programming in general), so I’m now trying to load the balance on page load, then post the updated balance amount back to my database using AJAX every 60 seconds, or whenever the user closes the browser window, refreshes the page or navigates away from the page. I don’t know if it’s possible to do all these things, or where to start, maybe this is a really bad way to go about this and maybe it's not scalable (maybe the database wouldn't support constant updates from 1000s of players by using this method)?

I would really appreciate any advice or help anyone could give me on any of this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I’m going to grab the balance from my database using AJAX on page load, and then place it inside a  but I have no idea how to make this figure decrement by 1 every time the Javascript object is clicked.

Here are two divs: you store the total number of coins in one and you click the second one to lose coins

```
<div id="coins">10</div>
<div onCLick="javascript:loseCoin()">If you click here it will cost you 1 coin</div>
```

Using a function to decrement the cost.

```
function loseCoin(){
    var coins = getElementByid("coins");
    var coins_nr = parseInt(coins.innerHTML,10);
    if( coins_nr> 0 ){
        coins.innerHTML = coins_nr - 1;
    } else {
        showModal();
    }
}
```

Where `showModal()` will be your modal (ask if you don't know how to make it)

As for updating the database every 60 sec, you would need a timer loop such as:

```
setInterval(function () {
      // get number of coins from your div's innerHTML
      // then call your ajax controller to update DB
}, 60000);
```

An example of ajax using javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
    if(xhr.status == 200){
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
      console.log('something else other than 200 was returned');
    }
  }
}
xhr.open("POST", "url_of_your_controller_here", true);
xhr.send("coins="+ coins_nr);
```

> (maybe the database wouldn't support constant updates from 1000s of
>   players by using this method)?

Any decent server should have no problem handling 1000 requests every 60 sec, but it may depend on how many other requests it has and the complexity of your requests.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to decrement a visible counter in the window on each click, you can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="coinsRemaining">20</div>
```

code:

```
// use whatever click handler is appropriate to your app
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("coinsRemaining");
    // get current display text and convert to number
    var cnt = +elem.textContent;
    --cnt;
    if (cnt >= 0) {
        elem.textContent = cnt;
    }
    if (cnt <= 0) {
        alert("There are no more coins");
    }    
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/s9jb6uhf/

---

It seems like you don't need to update the database on every click unless there's some realtime aspect of your coin balance that affects other users.  If you're just keeping track of your coin balance for future web page visits, then you could update the database much less often than every click.